# Are there traces of lost PIE laryngeals in Sanskrit?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, sanskrit

I read on wiki that

"Hittite retains laryngeals that disappeared entirely in Sanskrit (but left plenty of traces showing that it must once have existed).
In Proto-Indo-Iranian, the laryngeals merged as one phoneme /*H/ and there are some instances of this /*H/ survived into Rigvedic Sanskrit and Avestan as unwritten glottal stops as evidenced by metrics"

Can somebody elaborate please.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Lehmann's 1951 *Proto-Indo-European Phonology* (which is admittedly somewhat outdated but is the best resource I have on this), there are three main reasons to postulate some sort of reflex of laryngeals in Vedic Sanskrit.

One, as Mellifluous mentions, is aspiration when laryngeals came after a stop, as in *tíṣṭhati* "stand" from the zero-grade of **steh₂*. But this could have happened well before Vedic.

Another is lengthening in certain compounds. For example, *abhí* "to, for, on" generally has a short *ĭ* in compounds. But certain roots cause the vowel to lengthen: *abh**ī**sat* "surpass" < **h₁es-*. These roots also often have a lengthened augment.

Finally, and most convincingly, Vedic meter sometimes requires a long vowel to be read as two short vowels in hiatus; this is what the quote in your question is talking about. For example, *yānti* "go" (from **yeh₂*) often needs to be read as three syllables, implying it was originally **yaHánti*.

In particular, superlatives in *-iṣṭha-* tend to show this hiatus when applied to stems ending in a long vowel: *déṣṭha* "most generous" < *dā* < **deh₃* has to be read as **daHiṣṭha*. And one general tenet of the laryngeal theory is that all roots in PIE consisted of two groups of consonants; stems which end in a long vowel, like *dā*, generally come from that second group consisting of a single laryngeal.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, yes. One of the origins of the Sanskrit voiceless aspirate is a PIE cluster of PLOSIVE + LARYNGEAL. I know only one word that illustrates this:

- **पृथ्वी** *pṛthvī́* ('earth') > PIE *pl̥th₂-éwih₂ > *pléth₂us ('broad land')

<sub>(This information comes from the [Wikitionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80#Sanskrit) on the Sanskrit word *पृथ्वी*.)</sub>

Comment: An even clearer example is the word for ‘path’, where the cluster is paradigmatic: it shows up only in cases where the laryngeal-containing suffix is in the zero grade. See [the Wiktionary entry]() for a bunch of different suggested reconstructions. Granted, the voiceless aspirate has been generalised in Sanskrit there, but if you look at Avestan, it retains the plain stop in the nominative _pantā̊_ and the cluster in the genitive _paθō_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. It is a good idea to mention your sources, https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/39086/how-do-we-know-that-avestan-is-sister-of-vedic-sanskrit-and-not-its-daughter/39087?noredirect=1#comment91069_39087

Comment: @fdb I’m not sure what that comment has to do with anything, but I did intend to give a source – I just forgot to edit the comment and add in the actual URL (pasting doesn’t work in the iOS app, and I was already halfway through typing when I remembered). I meant to link to [PIIr. _*pántaH-_](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-Iranian/pántaHs) on Wiktionary.

Comment: Just to confirm if i got this right: PIE cluster of t and h₂ turned into the sanskrit थ ? Do i get it right?

Comment: @NikosPavlopoulos: Yep!